# Difference between Filter in join verses filter in where clause (T-sql)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, left-join, where-clause

Using Microsoft T-SQL, I know there is a difference in the result set between putting a filter in the join verses putting the filter in the where clause, because I get a different row count, and its hard to pin point, because it is a complex query with thousands of rows.

So does anybody know how this might lead to different results?

I feel safer with the where clause, but I am curious why the other one didn't get the same results.

```
Select
    .....
left outer join 
    datamart_agent ag on a.CUSTOMER_TKN = ag.customer_tkn 
                      and a.CUSTOMER_ACCT_TKN = ag.customer_acct_tkn 
                      and a.ACCOUNT_PKG_TKN = ag.account_pkg_tkn
--where (commented out)
   and ag.TYPE_DESC = 'Agent'
```

versus

```
Select
    .....
left outer join 
    datamart_agent ag on a.CUSTOMER_TKN = ag.customer_tkn 
                      and a.CUSTOMER_ACCT_TKN = ag.customer_acct_tkn 
                      and a.ACCOUNT_PKG_TKN = ag.account_pkg_tkn
where
    --and (commented out)
    ag.TYPE_DESC = 'Agent'
```

Comment: To get true LEFT JOIN result, put the ag condition in the ON clause. If you have it in the WHERE clause, you'll get regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: An `outer join` returns rows from one side, left or right, that have no matching row(s) on the other side. The `on` clause defines the matching criteria and allows for NULLs. You can use a `where` clause , but you need to code it to correctly handle NULLs, e.g. `... where ag.Type_Desc is NULL or ag.Type_desc = 'Agent';` in order for it to work as intended.

Comment: Who marked this down?  What's wrong with the question....?

Answer (score -1):

If condition is in your where clause then it will drop all records for which no match was found.  It is a like an eraser.  I deletes all records for which no match was found (Type_Desc is null).

The safer thing, if you are actually seeking left join, is to put the condition in the on clause.  If there was no match, it will still come in the result.  When Type_Desc is null, it means you don't know who the agent is, but if you don't know, you don't want to delete the record....

Comment: why the negative.  this answer is perfect for me!